# Is it possible to log a property in serilog but not display it in message field?

Tags: serilog

The standard way to log a message in serilog is something like

```
Byte[] buffer;
...

log.Debug("Counted {Length} bytes in the buffer {@Buffer}", buffer.Length, buffer);
```

This would add `Length` property as a long/int and `Buffer` property as text with hexadecimal format.

This also has the consequence that a message property is added with string representation of both `Length` and `Buffer`, something like `Counted 6 bytes in the buffer ABC456`. Since `Buffer` is a hexadecimal string I do not want to display it in the `message` but would like to have it as a property of the event.

Is there a way that I can ignore `Buffer` from the `message` field?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PushProperty` to add additional properties that will be added to each logging call made within the using block.

```
        using (LogContext.PushProperty("Buffer", buffer))
        {
            Log.Debug("Counted {Length} bytes in the buffer", buffer.Length);
        }
```